# How to fix Sketchup in Wine when tool starts, but displays empty workspace?

Tags: wine

I've installed wine 1.6 and winetricks in an Linux Mint 15 system, then downloaded the latest Sketchup2013 'Make' Windows-Installer and installed through wine.
I've prepared the wine environment with starting as WINEARCH=win32, installed corefonts and ie8 and enabled the override for the 'riched20' libraries. (I've no idea what the last bit does, but it was advised in some guides.) I've also tried without these steps. Only the win32 seems to make a difference, as the installer will complain about not finding SP2 otherwise.

Sketchup is installed successfully and starts, but displays an empty viewport.
The program is responsive and everything works, it's just that you can't see anything.
I don't get any OpenGL error and the registry entries seem fine, according to the OpenGL issue workarounds floating around the net.

I still think it has something to do with OpenGL not working properly, maybe not in the wine environment, but in the linux system?

I'm running on a Lenovo W520 with Nvida/Intel hybrid cards, but only the NVida card is active and the properitary nvidia (319) drivers are installed. GLXGears runs fine, but clamps at 2x the refresh rate. glxinfo outputs

```
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
server glx version string: 1.4
```

I'm willing to try any linux or wine OpenGL tests to narrow down the problem, if you can offer any advise on what to use.

Answer (score 1):

This is what fixed the **blank window** and **update lags** for me when running SketchUp 8 under Wine and Ubuntu 12.04. Start SkethUp like this:

```
vblank_mode=0 wine /your/path/to/SketchUp.exe
```

In my case I created a shell script to start SketchUp with this command:

```
#!/bin/bash
vblank_mode=0 wine $HOME/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/Google/Google\ SketchUp\ 8/SketchUp.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

SketchUp may hang or crash when you try to select a Template. To workaround this, open Sketch 2014 properties menu, in shortcut command, add `/DisableRubyAPI` at the end.

[image]
<sub>(source: [sysads.co.uk](https://www.sysads.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/sketchup-04.png))</sub>